# Как вывести список категорий вместе с подкатегориями и постами в WP?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Как лучше вывести список на одной странице со следующей структурой:

```
Категория
  -Подкатегория
  -Подкатегория
  -Пост
  -Подкатегория
  -Пост

Категория
  -Подкатегория
  -Подкатегория
  -Пост
  -Подкатегория
  -Пост
```

И тд. Проблема в том, что нужно смешивать подкатегории (термы) и посты, относящиеся к родительской категории. Есть в уме пара костылей, но, мб, есть более правильный вариант. Также думал насчет кастомного запроса напрямую к БД, дабы получить готовый массив.

Comment: Сперва get_categories() или get_terms(). В полученном массиве проверка на родителя категории - если родитель есть, то получаем посты через get_posts(). Не пойму в чем именно сложность.

Comment: Первый делом это и пришло в голову, получить массивы и объединить (для сортировки). Думал, мб есть более правильный вариант. P.S Просто, что-то мне подсказывает, что при переборе род. категорий будет затратным для каждой делать запросы на получение термов, постов и их склейку.

Comment: Забыл упомянуть, вывод на архивной странице кастомного типа записи с кастомной таксономией.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$parent_id = 5;
echo '<h2>Услуги</h2>';

# получаем дочерние рубрики
$sub_cats = get_categories( array(
    'child_of' => $parent_id,
    'hide_empty' => 0
) );
if( $sub_cats ){
    foreach( $sub_cats as $cat ){

        // Данные в объекте $cat

        // $cat->term_id
        // $cat->name (Рубрика 1)
        // $cat->slug (rubrika-1)
        // $cat->term_group (0)
        // $cat->term_taxonomy_id (4)
        // $cat->taxonomy (category)
        // $cat->description ()
        // $cat->parent (0)
        // $cat->count (14)
        // $cat->object_id (2743)
        // $cat->cat_ID (4)
        // $cat->category_count (14)
        // $cat->category_description ()
        // $cat->cat_name (Рубрика 1)
        // $cat->category_nicename (rubrika-1)
        // $cat->category_parent (0)

        echo '<h3>'. $cat->name .'</h3>';

        # получаем записи из рубрики
        $myposts = get_posts( array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'category'    => $cat->cat_ID,
            'orderby'     => 'post_date',
            'order'       => 'DESC',
        ) );
        # выводим записи
        global $post;
        foreach($myposts as $post){
            setup_postdata($post);
            echo '<li><a href="'. get_permalink() .'">'. get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
        }
        wp_reset_postdata(); // сбрасываем глобальную переменную пост

    }
}
```

Comment: Это понятно, вывести отдельно категории, их подкатегории и посты я могу,суть в том, что мне нужно объединить вывод подкатегорий и постов, затем отсортировать их ) Подкатегории и посты род. категории должны выводиться на одном уровне. Есть вариант тупо склеить полученные массивы и уже сделать сортировку средствами PHP, при постраничном кэше и малом коль-ве элементов, на производительности отразиться не должно.